# stubbing chained methods in PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I need to stub following call in PowerMockito.

```
appAcceptedDoc.getAppointmentAccepted().getRequestResponse().getRequestersID().getStringValue()
```

I know this can be done in Mockito using RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS as addional parameter in when mock is called , but how can be this be done using PowerMockito/ But seems does not accept this same arg in as Mockito does.

```
AppointmentAcceptedDocument appAcceptedDoc = Mockito.mock(AppointmentAcceptedDocument.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS); - Possible

AppointmentAcceptedDocument appAcceptedDoc = PowerMockito.mock(AppointmentAcceptedDocument.class, <?RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS?>); - Not possible
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found you can do this powermockito as you simply do with Mockito

Following will work

```
AppointmentAcceptedDocument appAcceptedDoc = PowerMockito.mock(AppointmentAcceptedDocument.class,  Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

Hope it helps someone!